# nested div hides the text in parent div

Tags: css, html

I am facing problem with nested divs. Text on parent div would get hidden from div in front.
Nested div "numReview" is set to be bottom left of parent div Bodyboxleft. 
Reason I want numReview to be on bottom left is because some pages would have less content some pages would have more content. When on page with more content, div:numReview  would hide   bottom 80px of content in bodyboxleft div.

fiddle link page is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/CANu4/1/

Comment: Do you have to position the footer absolutely?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `position: absolute;` with `float:left;`..............

remove `position:absolute;` so that #numReview won't go over the text

```
#numReview {
    width: 820px;
    height: 80px;
    float:left;
    background-color: #C0BFBF; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you are using position absolute, use the top property to place it in required position, though as there is no need of absolute on the page, you could do without it.